# Why can't I kill thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

Dear All I have this type of code:

```
public class Testimplements Runnable  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        InTheLoop l= new InTheLoop();
        Thread th = new Thread(l);
        th.start();
        th.interrupt();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        int count = 0;
        for (Integer i = 0; i <=10000000000000000000; i++) { 
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is ways to kill thread. For instance:

```
 // Example 1
 if (Thread.interrupted()){
                 return;
 }


// Example 2
   if(flag){ // volatile
   return;
    }
```

but can't I kill the thread without if statement?

Comment: Of course not. The thread must *know* what is being done to it, and must take explicit measures to end in a safe way. There is no equivalent of "process isolation" for threads so if you abruptly kill a thread, the whole JVM is destabilized.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `stop()` method if you really have to, but be aware that it is inherently unsafe and deprecated.
See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/concurrency/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html for details.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you have to implement the interruption policy for your thread yourself, how it handles the interrupt call and when it stops etc.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Answer (score 1):

Instead of thread better use [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for more control on threads.

Read more in [oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html) and here is [tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)

Answer (score 0):

This subject is very important and I could not find any clear answer for That so I write a sample code with OOP form to explain that

```
import threading
import time
import tkinter as tk


class A(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self ,*args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.count = 0
        self._running = True
        self.Do = 0
        A.Run(self)

    def Thread_Terminate(self):                     # a method for killing the Thread
        self._running =False
        self.T.join()

        self.Btn2.config (state='normal')
        self.Btn1.config (state='disabled')

    def Thread_Restart(self):                       # a thred for Start and Restart the thread
        self.Btn1.config (state='normal')
        self._running = True

        self.T = threading.Thread(target=self.Core) # define Thread

        if (self.T.is_alive() != True):             # Cheak the Thread is that alive
            self.T.start()

        self.Btn2.config (state='disabled')

    def Window (self):
        self.title(" Graph ")
        self.geometry("300x300+100+100")
        self.resizable(width=False, height=False)

        self.Lbl1 = Label(self,text = '0' ,font=('Times', -50, 'bold'), fg='Blue')
        self.Lbl1.pack()
        self.Lbl1.place(x=130, y=30 )

        self.Btn1 = Button(self,text= 'Thread OFF',width=25,command = self.Thread_Terminate)
        self.Btn1.pack()
        self.Btn1.place(x=50,y=100)
        self.Btn1 ['state'] = 'disable'

        self.Btn2 = Button(self, text='Thread ON', width=25, command=self.Thread_Restart)
        self.Btn2.pack()
        self.Btn2.place(x=50, y=140)

        self.Ent1 = Entry(self, width  = 30, fg='Blue')
        self.Ent1.pack()
        self.Ent1.place(x=50, y=180)

    def Core(self):                                 # this method is the thread Method
        self.count = 0
        i = self.Ent1.get()
        if (i==''):
            i='10'

        while (self._running and self.count<int(i)):
            self.count +=1

            self.Lbl1.config(text=str(self.count))

            print(str (self.count)+'Thread Is ON')
            time.sleep(0.5)

    def Run(self):
        A.Window(self)
        self.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Obj1 = A()
```